# Create an array from two input fields in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, events

Newbie React Question.
Assuming the following inputs

```
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <input
              className="form-control"
              name="manufacturer"
              type="text"
              onChange={handleReferencesChange}
              value={references}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="col-md-6">
            <input
              className="form-control"
              name="vehicleNumber"
              type="text"
              onChange={handleReferencesChange}
              value={references}
            />
          </div>
```

I wrote the function handleReferencesChange to grab the values of both inputs inside an array (references) which will then be pushed into the database (mongoDB)

```
  const handleReferencesChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setValues({ ...values, references: [], [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
```

Unfortunately I can not can not populate the references array (which I already initialized as and empty array)

Please can you help me understand why the values are not stored in the array but instead created as separated values. See screenshot below.

[image: JSON.stringify Screeshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setValues` code says, "take all the values, add an empty `references` array to it, then add/overwrite the field name of the input with the value from the event".

If you want to push stuff into an array, you need to use `push`.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

```
const handleReferencesChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newReferences = values.references.push({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    const newValues = {...values, references: newReferences}
    setValues(newValues);
  }
```

Comment: Hello Jmargolisvt, Thanks! Your solution is working. Though strangely, every time I press a key on the input a new array is created. May you please help me further?

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  I edited my answer.

Comment: Good Morning @jmargolisvt. I tested your new answer and received an error when  I'm typing. The error says: TypeError: values.references.push is not a function. It seems like the array "references" is undefined, so what I did was declaring the array inside the handle function. But nothing has changed. Please can you help me out? :-)

Comment: My answer assumes you have `references` already in your state object.  If not, you need to declare it and (probably) check for it's existence before running `push` on it.

Comment: Thanks Man! Tested and working !